# Vertical-align is not working on li

Tags: css, html, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to have my `li` element align in the middle - vertically.

But it looks like `vertical-align` is not working. Any ideas?

**HTML**

```
<body>
   <div class="toolbar">
      <ul>
         <li>
            <input type="radio" value="one" name="try" />
            <img src="try1_30X30.png"/>
            hello
         </li>
         <li>
            <input type="radio" value="two" name="try" />
            <img src="try2_30X30.png"/>
            world
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.toolbar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    height: 50px;
}

.toolbar ul li {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to apply the `vertical-align` property to the `img` tag itself.

Please see code below or working example here (http://jsbin.com/oxoMeCo/1/)

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    .toolbar ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        height: 50px;
    }
    .toolbar ul li
    {
        float: left;
        display: block;
        line-height: 50px;
        padding-left: 10px;
    }

    .toolbar ul li img {
        vertical-align:middle;

    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="toolbar">
     <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" value="one" name="try" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30">
            hello
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" value="two" name="try" />
            <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30">
            world
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```